# how to put localhost laravel project on Go Daddy server?

Tags: php, laravel

how to put localhost laravel project on Go Daddy server?
I have a PHP7 project with MySQL running nicely on my "localhost/laravel/public" path.

Now i want to put this working project on GoDaddy server using FileZilla.
How and where i should put which files so that it should run same like my localhost?

My other normal PHP coding files (eg .php) are already working good on GoDaddy server. but i don't know how to run laravel project with its own structure or something.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to this guide: [The simple guide to deploy Laravel 5 application on shared hosting](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e)

Comment: thanks @Jesús Amieiro
It worked.
I will try routes settings now